# How do you show files outside the pathspec when doing gitk

Tags: git, gitk

I want to perform `gitk` to visually see which commits have core files that have changed but I also want to know which commits touch files that are also touched within the commit

When I do `gitk core-dir/` as I expect I see the commits that touch core-dir/ but when I am traversing through gitk I only see the files that were modified in core-dir rather than the files that were touched in the commit.

I can't really find the info I want in https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gitk.1.html but I may just be looking for an incorrect keyword